# "I came, I saw, I am playing" = "veni, vidi, ludo"?

Tags: idiom, translation-check, english-to-latin-translation

This came up as an idea for a team phrase for a sports team. The purpose would be to convey that people visited, joined, and are *still* playing the sport. (Disclaimer: I know almost nothing of Latin.)

I think "play" is *ludo* and would sound nice if they could say *veni, vidi, ludi.* However, if the *-i* indicates past tense then that's not entirely right, it should be present tense.

What is the present tense of "to play", and how would you suggest to use this in a team phrase?

*Edit: I know the alliteration is broken, but it's okay for the team.*

Comment: Your translation is fine (grammatically), but it sounds funny. Caesar's quote works because of the alliteration.

Comment: The perfect of *ludo* is *lusi*, not *ludi*, FYI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no specific conjugation for the English present continuous in Latin. There is only present tense. As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_conjugation#Present-tense_system) states:

> A present tense like *portō* can be translated as "I carry," "I do carry," or "I am carrying".

Thus, your translation is correct. The first person, indicative, present tens of "I play" is *[ludo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ludo#Inflection)*.

If you want to put further emphasis in that you are still playing, you can add a word for "still". As far as I know, some options are *etiam*, *adhuc*, *tamen*. So your phrase could be

> veni, vidi, ludo etiam

Someone might have a better idea which word fits better the context. I'm not an expert.

PS: Tom suggests *adhuc* "better implies that the subject is continuing to play, even as he speaks."

Comment: I think that _veni, vidi, adhuc ludo_ better implies that the subject is continuing to play, even as he speaks.

Comment: @TomCotton Thanks. I think a question about the differences might be interesting!